# How to duplicate Console text to text file?

Tags: c#

How to duplicate Console.WriteLine to text file?

```
static void ConsoleWrite(String value, ConsoleColor color)
        {         
        Console.ForegroundColor = color;
        FileStream ostrm;
        StreamWriter writer;
        TextWriter oldOut = Console.Out;

        try
        {
            ostrm = new FileStream("./logfile.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
            writer = new StreamWriter(ostrm);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cannot open logfile.txt for writing");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            return;
        }
        Console.SetOut(writer);
        Console.SetError(writer);
        Console.WriteLine(value.PadRight(Console.WindowWidth - 1));
        Console.SetError(oldOut);
        Console.SetOut(oldOut);
        Console.WriteLine(value.PadRight(Console.WindowWidth - 1));
        writer.Close();
        ostrm.Close();
    }
```

This code writes only the last line.

(I need to display text in the console and at the same time save text to a file.)

```
ConsoleWrite("test1",ConsoleColor.Red);
ConsoleWrite("test2",ConsoleColor.Red);
ConsoleWrite("test3",ConsoleColor.Red);
```

In the file only one line is saved: "**test3**"  :(

Comment: Have you tried flushing the writer before closing it?  `writer.Flush()`

Comment: All the same only the last line is saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `FileMode.OpenOrCreate` sets the Position to 0, so the file is overwritten each time you open it. For a quick fix, use `FileMode.Append`.

But a more maintainable solution would probably be using a logging library like Log4Net.

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a class derived from `TextWriter`
2. Allow it to takes as many instances of you want (say `writers`)
3. Implement `TextWriter` in your derived class to output the data to every instance of `writers`
4. Create an instance of your derived class (eg: `new Foo(Console.Out, File.CreateText("Foo"))`)
5. `Console.SetOut(the_instance_of_your_textwriter)`
6. **PROFIT!!!**

Comment: @BrainOverflow: It is trivial and will be well worth for learning how (some) OO principles work.

Answer (score 2):

```
ostrm = new FileStream("./logfile.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
```

You're using the wrong FileMode.

OpenOrCreate results in a stream that begins at the start of the file. Thus, you overwrite existing data. Every time you call this function, the existing contents are overwritten - which is why you only have the last line.

You want to use FileMode.Append, which will open the file if it exists, create it if it doesn't, and importantly will seek to the end of the file and then start writing from there. Each time you call your function, you will then be adding data on to the end of the file.

See [the MSDN documentation on FileMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode.aspx)